# Bottom sheet closes when keyboard opens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-design, bottom-sheet

I added a very basic layout using Bottom sheet behavior. The bottom sheet's layout has a EditText.

When keyboard opens, it closes the bottom sheet layout. What are some ways I can keep the bottom sheet view group there when keyboard is opened?

Comment: do you find the answer for this? I have the same issue

Comment: @rand I have not found any answers. I moved on mimic'ing bottom sheet functionality using a dialog fragment.

Answer (score 4):

could you post the entire layout?

In my case, my bottom sheet use `layout_gravity = "bottom"`

After I remove the `layout_gravity` the bottom sheet is not disappearing anymore.

Answer (score 3):

For me this works.

```
<activity   
...        
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it works in BottomSheet, but you may give a try for the following line in your AndroidManifest file.

```
<activity
...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> 
</activity>
```

Comment: I've tried that. Bottom sheet closes as keyboard appears.